# Check progress on NTFS compression

Tags: ntfs, compression

I have a NTFS disk with compression enabled and moved a couple of files (300gb~) to it.

Every time I refresh the windows explorer window I see that the free space on the disk is growing, which I assume it is because the compression is still happening.

Can I check the progress on the compression? How do I know when it is over?